# How to associate instances from different classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, instance

I want to be able to initialize a new Car object and pass it a Person object in the parameters, so it can be saved in that Person's @cars array.  Currently, I take this approach:

```
person = Person.new("Michael")
car = Car.new("Honda", "Accord")
person.add_car(car)
person.add_car(Car.new("Ford", "Taurus"))
person.add_car(Car.new("Toyota", "Prius"))
person.display
```

However, I'd like to be able to create a new car instance and pass it the Person object I want it associated with.  For example:

```
person = Person.new("Michael")
Car.new("Honda", "Accord", person)
Car.new("Toyota", "Camry", person)
Car.new("Chevy", "Tahoe", person)
person.display
```

Is that even possible?

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    super
    @name = name
    @cars = []
  end

  def display
    puts "#{@name} has #{@cars.length} cars"
    puts "----------------------------"
    @cars.each do |car|
      puts "#{car.make} #{car.model}"
    end
  end

  def add_car(car)
    @cars.push(car)
  end

end 

class Car

  attr_accessor :make, :model

  def initialize(make, model)
    @model = model
    @make = make
  end

  def display
    puts "#{@make} #{@model}"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, `Car#initialize` can call methods on its arguments:

```
class Car
  def initialize(make, model, person = nil)
    @model = model
    @make  = make
    person.add_car(self) if(person)
  end
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my implementation:

```
class Car 
  attr_accessor :make, :model

  def initialize(make, model)
    self.make = make
    self.model= model
  end
end
```

**Person class**

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :cars

  def initialize(name, cars=[])
    self.name = name
    self.cars = cars || []
  end

  def add_car(*args)
    raise ArgumentError, 'invalid arguments'  if (
        (args.size > 2 or args.size == 0) or 
        (args.size == 1 and !args[0].is_a?(Car))
      )
    new_car = (args.size == 2) ? Car.new(*args) : args[0]
    self.cars << new_car
    new_car
  end

end
```

Now you can:

```
person = Person.new("Michael")
car = Car.new("Honda", "Accord")
person.add_car(car)
person.add_car("Ford", "Taurus")
person.add_car("Toyota", "Prius")
person.display
```

The add_car method creates a new car when make and model are passed as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as `mu is too short`'s answer demonstrated, but that doesn't really make sense in my opinion. Your cars can't be used in any context without a `Person`, and said parameter contributes no data necessary to construct the `Car` object.

I would design such an API as follows:

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def cars
    @cars ||= Array.new  # Equivalent to @cars || @cars = []
  end
end

person = Person.new 'Michael'

taurus = Car.new 'Ford', 'Taurus'
prius = Car.new 'Toyota', 'Prius'

person.cars << taurus << prius << Car.new('Honda', 'Accord')
```

This is a simpler and more direct form of `KandadaBoggu`'s implementation that takes advantage of the `Array#<<` method in order to naturally associate `Car`s with a `Person`, and also doubles as an attribute reader.